# Orchard CMS ContentShapes - can I add a wrapper?

Tags: orchardcms, shapes

I have a resource in OrchardCMS that I'm displaying through a number of smaller shapes (so that I can adjust the layout order in placement.info).

In the Driver I am returning these parts through the use of returning a Combined(ContentShape(...), ContentShape(...), ContentShape(...)) etc

However I would like the HTML of each of the smaller shapes to appear within an HTML wrapper (such as a div or article or suchlike)

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you are trying to achieve but it isn't really a feasible scenario. A wrapper is applied to a shape and combined returns several shapes. As you say, each shape has an entry in the placement.info file, so you could easily have these shapes within different content zones or zones spread around your page, where a wrapper would just not work. Make sense?

The answer is probably that you need to create an override for the content view of the content type you are displaying and add the stuff you want to put in your wrapper in there. e.g. if your content type is called MyType and the displayed type was detail, your view would be called Content-MyType.Detail.cshtml.

Comment: OK I see where you're coming from. I'll have a think about whether to give what you suggest a go.. .or whether I should just be coming at this from a totally different angle.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean an Orchard wrapper (whole new cshtml file), or just a HTML element?

In the latter case you can do in your part view:

```
@{
    var tag = Tag(Model, "article");
}

@tag.StartElement

    stuff

@tag.EndElement
```

If you want to wrap a (common) wrapper around your elements, you can do the following in your placement.info:

```
<Place Parts_MyPart="Content:1;Wrapper=MyWrapper" />
<Place Parts_MyOtherPart="Content:2;Wrapper=MyWrapper" />
```

And create a MyWrapper.cshtml:

```
<article>
    @Display(Model.Child)
</article>
```

Comment: Surely this puts a wrapper around each of the view files rather than the wrapper around all of them?

I have a single part and driver, but it returns a number of views/shapes through the use of the Combined() in the driver display, so each of these shapes have an entry in the placement.info (so that people can turn them each off/on)

Thanks!